# Can the Spring cache framework be used to cache a non-serializable objects?

Tags: spring, ehcache, serializable

I have a requirement to cache an object that can't be serialized. I am looking for some methodology to cache these kind of objects via a Wrapper. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

The objects you want to cache need not to be serialized, but of course the keys you generate to store your corresponding objects must be serialized.

- [Caching Example with Spring Annotations and Ehcache](http://web.archive.org/web/20130605094701/http://developers-blog.org/blog/de/2010/06/07/Caching-Example-with-Spring-Annotations-and-Ehcache)
- [Making things @Cacheable](http://web.archive.org/web/20140403022227/http://www.bagdemir.com/2011/10/06/making-things-cacheable/)
- [ehcache-spring-annotations (Using Cacheable)](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable)
- [ehcache-spring-annotations (Frequently Asked Questions)](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)